# How to use embed query with wordpress rest api?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I use the _embed query with wordpress rest api and it works like this :

```
sitename/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed
```

And I get the expected results .
But when I use it with search method it doesn't return me the _embedded version of posts :

```
sitename/wp-json/wp/v2/search?_embed
```

How can I use the search rest api with embed ?

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded by ignoring the '/search' service and adding a 'search' url parameter to the '/posts' service

So it would look like this

```
sitename/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed&search=searchTerm
```